# Git push rejected, don't want to pull either

Tags: git, github

Here's git status after I did git add and commit of two files(model.R and preprocessing.R):

```
Macs-MacBook:crime_type_class_mlmodel macuser$ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 9 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    20170628_somefile.txt
    deleted:    model.R
    deleted:    somecsv.csv
    deleted:    somecsv1.csv
    modified:   rscripts/.RData
    modified:   rscripts/.Rhistory
    modified:   rscripts/preprocessing.R
    deleted:    somecsv2.csv

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .DS_Store
    .RData
    .Rhistory
    database snippets.sql
    output_csvs/
```

I'm trying to commit the two files from my local directory to github.

```
git push origin master


To https://github.com/ourco/myprojectrepo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ourco/myprojectrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So, I tried git pull as suggested by the message:

Macs-MacBook:crime_type_class_mlmodel macuser$ `git pull origin master`

```
From https://github.com/ourco/myprojectrepo.git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    rscripts/.RData
    rscripts/.Rhistory
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Those two files, .RData and .RHistory don't show in the repo when I visit in my browser. I don't want them in github and I don't want to overwrite them locally. Those two files should be on my local dir only. So, I'm concerned about overwriting them.

How can I commit both model.R and preprocessing.R files to github?

Comment: you might want to consider adding .RData and .Rhistory to the .gitignore file. You can check out https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/R.gitignore for sample .gitignore file for R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add those files to your `.gitignore`, then git won't care about changes made to them, and thus won't complain about conflicts.

Also, you can stash them temporarily:

`git stash save`

Then do your merge/rebase/pull

`git stash pop`

And they're back.

Additionally, if you are finding that other people are adding them to the repo (by doing a naughty `git add -a` or `git add .`, without instead using the interactive `git add -p` flag) then you should commit the `.gitignore` to the repo with the changes.  Unfortunately you'll need to do it in steps because those files are already tracked:  delete the files, commit the delete, push it up, update the `.gitignore`, commit & push that, then restore the files locally. Let your other developers know as well that they should back theirs up.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful in understanding. So I should create a new file in my di r.gitignore and add the path to both files I want ignored. Stash sounds interesting too, I'll look it up

Comment: I added the two files to .gitignore. Then I tried git push > error message about "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind". So then I tried `git pull origin master' which gave "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.". Also, to be explicitly clear, my local directory is the most up to date files, it's where I've been working on updating these scripts all week. Therefore, If I do a git pull would that not over write the newer script that's been worked on with the older version that's currently on github? Thanks for you help thus far

Comment: Have you committed this newer script?

Comment: Adding the files to `.gitignore` *is not enough*. You also need to get rid of the files in the history.